# How does authorization work in application that runs on local network?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In a Web application in order to fetch the data we could request the user to be authenticated first. Authentication is also done on the web server side.

What about local network application, where there is no service involved, and the application connects to database directly (database in located on a server PC). How would I do things like: this table can only be read by authenticated user, this table can only be read by all users, etc..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't connect to a database(mySQl, Oracle, SQLServer) without authentication.

Usually you would store the connection informations in a config file, but you can also not do so and ask your users to provide their own credential.

Most SGBD will let you configure read/write rights per user.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if application users/roles will be defined by the client itself, does that mean that Db administrator would need to create the exact same users for the database? And when I need to authorize some user, user name and password that user has entered in my application I will use in connection string? Is this the normal authentication procedure?

Comment: Giving direct access to your database to normal user is not a normal procedure :) But if you need to then you could use the already implemented SGBD authentication service. In this case, you will have to create the users at the SGBD layer. Notice that this can be done automatically using SQL queries. And yes, you will use the user credential in the connection string. The user will have limited access to the database as defined by the admin on the SGBD. This is exactly like the user system on linux.

Comment: Normal or not depends on what your security concerns are. Db admin would need to create enough users for your roles, how you map your user to role (i.e. directly using name/password, or having map user-> connection string) is your call. Note that storing connection strings with password embedded is security risk, also you seem to need one for "non-authenticated users" anyway...

Comment: Btw, if you are using SQLServer, then you can map windows users to the SGBD users using what is called WindowsAuthentication if I remember correctly. I think mySQL have similar feature with linux users. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: I can't see how non-authenticated users would have access to the database. Shouldn't this be prohibited by most SGBD?

Comment: Database server will be on the client's side. Are there some ground rules that common DB administrator would ask me to follow, since basically my software needs to create a database on the server. Can I safely asume that I will be able to do this: DB admin provides me with a (temp) user account that is able to create db. During database creating, I log in with given credentials, create db and create one admin user for this db. Then after I start the software, I can use the credentials of the user I created and make initial setup: create (users, roles, etc)

Comment: Or another way I could think that could happend, is that admin db does not allow me to access sql server at all, but asks for db create script, so I would handle him the create db script with one default admin user, that has all priviledges for this database. Would there be any other scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

IF I understand your question properly
If all the users on the network belong to the domain use windows authentication so your connection string would be something like:

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

otherwise you will have to use user authentication:

```
 Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

these are all done for sql server:

for others check [this](http://www.connectionstrings.com/).
 Hope it helps

Comment: I cannot rely on domain, since I need to allow different users to be able to log-in on the same windows account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure permissions for database itself the same way you would do for Web application. Normally you would grant a user that web app runs under enough permissions to perform all operations in DB, in case of desktop clients - grant appropriate permissions to individual users.

Note that such design exposes much more access to DB than one normally would be ok with.

Comment: Hi Alexei, since you have answered similarly as lcfseth did, can you please read the comment I posted on his answer, so I do not need to repeat the same question.